# Where can I find a comparsion of non-offical cooked rom/firmware of Galaxy S i9000?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, custom-roms, kernel

I've been searching around for the topic these few days. However, I am getting into a problem of information overflow - there are too many different version and custom kernal around. Most of them are still in active development with a chain of discussion on forum that is difficult to check what they actually are.

Do you know are there any feature matrix of these kernel?
If it is yet exists, I am going to build one from here. Please share the kernel/rom you found that

Comment: you may want to have a look here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=886000

Answer (score 3):

[CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) is a famous community-build Android ROM for multiple Android devices. Give you a very different user experience.

> CyanogenMod is a free, community built
>   distribution of Android 2.2 which
>   greatly extends the capabilities of
>   your phone.

- Require flash : Yes
- Custom ROM: Yes (that's mean no Samsung stuffs, changed app launcher, etc)
- Custom Kernel: Yes
- Lagfix: hot development
- Latest development: [Work in progress](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803103)

Comment: And there are stable releases of CyanogenMod based on the much newer Android 4.x sources than the official Samsung ROMs for Galaxy S.

Answer (score 1):

[Project Voodoo](http://project-voodoo.org/) is a community-build kernel based on Samsung official sources with minimized patches. It provide few fixes focusing on file system, visual and audio improvement, without a lot of changes feature add-on or changing of user experience.

> In a nutshell, voodoo replaces RFS
>   with EXT4 in order to greatly boost
>   your phone’s speed and user
>   experience.

- Require Rooted : No
- Custom ROM: No
- Custom Kernel: Yes
- Lagfix: Native ext4
- User option: multiple builds provied
- Latest stable: beta4 for 2.1
- Latest development: pre6 for 2.2;

Answer (score 1):

[One Click Lag Fix](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=784691) a one click application to fix the IO performance lag issue by using a ext2 on top on the original RFS. In addition, it provide few utility to optimize IO scheduler and also WiFi timeout.

> OCLF uses a loopback EXT2 mount on top
>   of RFS to store the RFS data inside

- Require Rooted : Yes
- Android App : Market (TODO: add link)
- Custom ROM: No
- Custom Kernel: ??
- Lagfix: ext2 on RFS
- User option: In app selection
- Latest stable: 2.2.8

Answer (score 0):

Doc's Froyo is pretty, great, and i think it's like the go to rom for the moment

Comment: Could you kindly provide a link and major focus of it? e.g. performance, power saving, special patches..etc